# How to find the max sum of a column in a dataframe regarding a condition of another column's value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

How to find the max sum of a column in a data frame regarding a condition of another column's value?

For example, I have a sorted dataframe(consider a pandas dataframe using Python):

Dataframe screenshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkUS6.png)

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Activity Name':['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
            'Time':[10,25,10,10,90,80],
            'Gain':[30,100,40,40,450,400],
            'Gain/min':[3,4,4,4,5,5]})
```

The "Name" column is the activity names I can participate. The "Time" column is the time that the corresponding activity consumes. The "Gain" column is the total gain I will obtain after I finish the activity. The "Gain/min" column is the gain I can receive through the activity in per-minute base.

I only have 120 minutes(let's say mins for the Time) to participate in these activities, and I can only participate one time for each activity. I don't necessarily need to fill all 120 minutes, but I can only receive gains after I finish the activity. Therefore, if the last activity I can select has the same "gains per minute" rate, I should attend the longer time one to receive a higher total gain within 120 minutes(If I take a break last 5 minutes, then these 5 mins are blank and wasted and I won't receive any gain for this 5 mins)

The sum of time is less than or equal to 120, and I want to maximize my gain within this 120 minutes period.

Could anyone please help me to output the activities plan that I should attend in this 120-min period?

It doesn't matter which activity to attend first or which one to attend in the second place. Just to list all the activities I should attend to maximize my gain.

If more than one plan can give the max gain and they have the same total gains, please print them all out(similar to a combination and permutation problem).

Consider this as a Pandas data frame using Python.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried and where you are running into issues: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: This is not a homework question. I just think of this question and have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the best way of doing it but this is how I solved the problem (if I've understood it correctly). Set the activity name to be the index and import "combinations". (if you're allowed to repeat activities just replace this with "combinations_with_replacement"). Also create a dictionary to store the results.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

df=pd.DataFrame({'Activity Name':['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
            'Time':[10,25,10,10,90,80],
            'Gain':[30,100,40,40,450,400],
            'Gain/min':[3,4,4,4,5,5]})

df.set_index('Activity Name', inplace=True)
possibilities = {}
```

You're definitely not going to be doing more than 12 activities as the shortest activity takes 10 minutes. So we'll assume you'll be doing between 1 and 12 activities.
We'll use the combinations function to find all the possible combinations of activities.
We'll call each 120 minute or less attempt a "go".
We'll use the sum of a list comprehension to find the amount of time each "go" takes and assign it to 't'.
Then if 't' is less than or equal to 120:
We use the sum of another list comprehension to calculate a score for that 'go' and add it to our dictionary.

```
for i in range(1,12):
    for go in combinations(df.index, i):
        t = sum([df.at[v,'Time'] for v in go])
        if t <= 120:
            score = sum([df.at[v, 'Gain'] for v in go])
            possibilities[go] = score
```

Then find the highest score among all the scores in our dictionary and store it in the variable 'best'.

```
best = max(possibilities.values())
```

Then iterate through the dictionary and delete any entries with a score lower than the best.

```
for key, value in list(possibilities.items()):
    if value < best:
        del possibilities[key]
```

The possibilities dictionary should now only contain the attempts with the highest score, with the activities done as the key and the sum of the "Gains" as the value.